# How to run MySQL bundle on Snow Leopard OS X

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to run the MySQL bundle on my Snow Leopard OS X.

To check if I had MySQL on my computer, I went to my terminal and typed "which mysql". The directory it gave me was "/usr/local/bin/mysql". I then typed "/usr/local/bin/mysql" and hit enter, but I got this message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I did a bit of research, and there was a webpage advocating that I change my php.ini file. Specifically, it said this:

> "In /etc/php.ini, replace the three occurences of
>   /var/mysql/mysql.sock by /tmp/mysql.sock:
>
> pdo_mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
>
> mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
>
> mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock "

I made the changes, restarted apache (by doing `sudo apachectl restart` in the terminal), and then typed "/usr/local/bin/mysql" again in the terminal and hit enter. I got the exact same error message that I got before.

So I didn't know what to do from here... I instead decided to try and start the MySQL server and see what happens. I entered "which mysql.server" in the terminal and hit enter, and the directory for this was "/usr/local/bin/mysql.server".

In the terminal, I typed `sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server start` and hit enter. When I did this, I got this message:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/santoshs-macbook.local.pid)
```

So now I am completely stuck. I really do not know how to proceed with running the MySQL bundle on Snow Leopard. What am I supposed to do? What am I doing wrong? Should I just download and install a new MySQL bundle? Any suggestions/edits to my post are appreciated.